# Echo session user name else echo 'visitor'

Tags: php, session

I need too echo session user name else echo as visitor

I used following code, it echo visitor and also php error message

```
<?php
 echo $_SESSION['username'];
 if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
 echo 'Visitor';
 }
?>
```

[image]

If registered user logged in it need to display `$_SESSION` name else it need to echo `VISITOR`

Comment: Use session_start() at every pages top before anything.

Comment: Maybe look at `else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check, if the username is set in the session before output it:

```
<?php
 if ( isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) {
   echo $_SESSION['username'];
 }
 if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
   echo 'Visitor';
 }
?>
```

And better:

```
<?php
 if ($user->is_logged_in()) {
   echo $_SESSION['username'];
 } else {
   echo 'Visitor';
 }
?>
```

And: You need to start your session with a `session_start()` call, too, e.g. at the beginning of your script, directly after the opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: i made session start in `configure.php`

Comment: You don't require/include your `configure.php` in your example, so we don't know that :) But if you already do it, ignore my last note :)

Answer (score 2):

you have to start the session and then to check if the index exist

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
} else {
     if (!$user->is_logged_in()) {
        echo 'Visitor';
     }
}
```